# char to LPCTSTR

Tags: model-view-controller, visual-c++, msdn

how to convert char to LPCTSTR in vc++

---

I am using MVC.

```
QByteArray qBary;
qBary.append(temp);
char toChar[512];
for(int ii = 0; ii < 512; ii++)
{ 
    toChar[ii] = qBary[ii];
    if(qBary[ii] == '\0') 
    {
        break;
    }
} 
SHFILEOPSTRUCT sf;
memset(&sf, 0, sizeof(sf)); 
sf.hwnd = 0;
sf.wFunc = FO_COPY;
sf.pFrom = toChar; // error occurring here
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are using MFC (is your label supposed to be MFC instead of MVC?):

```
char name[] = "your name";  
CString sName(name);  
LPCTSTR lpszName = sName;
```

if you are using Qt, take a look at [QString](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qstring.html) and [QByteArray](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qbytearray.html)

```
// (1)
QString filename;
LPCWSTR lpszFilename = filename.utf16(); // alternatively, .unicode()
// alternatively, (2)
QByteArray qBA("abcdef.txt");
QString qString(qBA);
LPCWSTR lpszFileName = qString.utf16(); // or, .unicode() , .utf8()

...
sf.pFrom = lpszFileName;
```

Comment: you should put your block of code in the question preceded by a newline and prefix them with 4 spaces for every line of codes. click 'edit' somewhere near your question.

Comment: it seems like you are using Qt, please add that to the label.

Comment: I am using MVC. 

    QByteArray qBary;
 qBary.append(temp);
 char toChar[512];
 for(int ii=0;ii<512;ii++)
    { 
    toChar[ii]=qBary[ii];
     if(qBary[ii]=='\0') 
     { break;
       } } 
     SHFILEOPSTRUCT sf;
     memset(&sf,0,sizeof(sf)); 
     sf.hwnd = 0;
     sf.wFunc = FO_COPY;
     sf.pFrom = toChar; // error occurring here