# error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'char *const ' to 'LPCTSTR'

Tags: visual-c++

```html
struct StaticString
{
 StaticString() { Str = NULL; }
 ~StaticString() { if(Str) delete [] Str; Str=0; }

 char* Str;

 void operator = (const char * pchar)
 {
  Str = new char[strlen(pchar)+1];
  strcpy(Str,pchar);
 }
 operator LPCTSTR() const
 {
  return Str;
 }
 operator PCHAR() const
 {
  return Str;
 }
 
};
```

error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'char *const ' to 'LPCTSTR'

Its from game . and how can i fix that?  i search in google but no one work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [char to LPCTSTR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536628/char-to-lpctstr)

Comment: Do you have UNICODE defined? You would be doing yourself a favor if you avoided TCHAR, forever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LPCSTR, LPCTSTR and LPTSTR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321413/lpcstr-lpctstr-and-lptstr)

Comment: I have my UNICODE defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LPCTSTR` is "long pointer to constant TCHAR string".

The `TCHAR` type is ancient. It dates back to the original transition from "ANSI" to "wide-character" Unicode with Windows 98/NT.

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
typedef wchar_t TCHAR;
#else
typedef char TCHAR;
#endif
```

Most projects these days default to `_UNICODE` which means `TCHAR` is not a `char` but is instead `wchar_t`.

See [What are TCHAR, WCHAR, LPSTR, LPWSTR, LPCTSTR (etc.)?](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/76252/what-are-tchar-wchar-lpstr-lpwstr-lpctstr-etc)

Generally you should avoid using these Windows portable types and stick with C++ standard types.